Error: Can't deploy more than one path. on prompt npx vercel kv create rate-limiting
Why do I get the following error Error: Can't deploy more than one path. when entering the prompt prompt npx vercel kv create rate-limiting into the command line?
I already tried to delete the vercel.json file as there are two cron jobs defined which according to the vercel AI assistant could possibly cause the issue.
Verion of Vercel CLI: 37.14.0

vercel is a shorthand for vercel deploy, and vercel kv create ... is attempting to run vercel deploy kv create.... You can check this with vercel kv --help:
vercel kv --help
Vercel CLI 37.14.0

  ▲ vercel deploy [project-path] [options]
(...)

Perhaps you want to deploy this example instead?
Is there a link where you saw this command by any chance?
